# parseInt not working for window.document

Tags: javascript

Is there a reason that this would not work?

```
 var xcurrent = parseInt(window.document.getElementById('firstdiv').style.left);
 var ycurrent = parseInt(window.document.getElementById('firstdiv').style.top);
```

I'm being told it's not an integer NaN.

Comment: Are you sure `left` and `top` are defined

Comment: I'm using firefox. That's what I'm trying to do...remove px so that I can perform some calculations.

Comment: [Works for me.](http://jsfiddle.net/AG3MQ/) Make sure you have a div with an ID of "firstdiv".

Comment: Try using offsetLeft: `xcurrent = window.document.getElementById('firstdiv').offsetLeft;`

Comment: How do you assign style.left and style.top to the element? element.style does not retrieve styles set by a global stylesheet

Comment: it is defined inline. And I just realized that it IS defined. If Idon't use parseInt() it returns that coordinate in px. But I want to use operators on it

Comment: Please note: `parseInt` takes two parameters, the first is the string to be used, the second is radix, the base to be used. In this case you want 10. So `parseInt(string_variable,10);`. Also, every call to `getElementById` takes a lot of time. It it better to call it once and store that value in a variable and then use that variable when you get the values. As a bonus it is less to type.

Comment: By the way, when is this code called? After the DOM is ready?

Comment: Note that in trying to resolve this issue it would've been useful to try `console.log(window.document.getElementById('firstdiv').style.left)` to check that what you were passing to `parseInt()` actually was a number...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a reason that this would not work?
>
> var xcurrent = parseInt(window.document.getElementById('firstdiv').style.left);

Quite a few, but the likely ones are:

1. If element with id 'firstdiv' doesn't exist, `window.document.getElementById('firstdiv')` will return `null`. Attempting to access the *style* property of `null` will throw an error. That's not the result you specified though.
2. The value returned by `.style.left` is an empty string. In that case, [parseInt](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.2.2) returns `NaN` per ECMA-262.

A safer approach is:

```
var el = document.getElementById('firstdiv');
var xcurrent

if (el) {
  xcurrent = parseInt(el.style.left);

  if (isNaN(xcurrent)) { 
    // there was no value for xcurrent, what now?
```

As Nathan said, you can use [offsetLeft](http://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view/#offset-attributes) instead.

Answer (score 2):

u̶ ̶n̶e̶e̶d̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶r̶e̶m̶o̶v̶e̶ ̶`̶p̶x̶`̶ ̶f̶r̶o̶m̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶s̶t̶r̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶ (doesn't matter on modern browsers)

make sure `window.document.getElementById('firstdiv').style.left` is defined. you can't access this property if it's defined only in CSS

Examples:

- CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/zuKYr/
- Inline: http://jsfiddle.net/zuKYr/1/
- JS: http://jsfiddle.net/zuKYr/2/

only style defined by JS and inline CSS is readable by JS.

Comment: No, `parseInt` will just stop parsing when it reaches non-numeric characters. `parseInt('123px')` will return the number `123`.

Comment: okay, yeah. I was trying to parse the place where I was defining top and left. Thanks for the help. Just wanted to make sure there wasn't some reason this wouldn't work.

Comment: @EXQStudio: The `parseInt` function will work consistently (for this purpose). The `getElementById` method works back to IE 5.5.

Answer (score 2):

It's not `parseInt` that isn't working, `NaN` suggests that the element you are trying to reference cannot be interpreted as an integer. Although it is difficult to say for certain, make sure that the elements you are referencing actually exist and see if you can access them at all before manipulating them. i.e check that `window.document.getElementById('firstdiv')` gives you anything before trying to do any more with it.

You also need to make sure that your css has actually set the attribute you are trying to retrieve otherwise you will get an `undefined`/`Nan` error.

Comment: when the element cannot be accessed, parseInt() wouldn't return anything, the script will stop executing with an error. It returns NaN because the value of element.style.left can't be converted into an integer by parseInt()

Comment: can't be converted to an integer? If it would normally return say 100px why wouldn't parseInt() return 100?

Comment: if the data isn't there then it won't be able to parse it.

Comment: @WilliamSmith—if the element doesn't exist, `getElementById` will return `null`. Attempting to access the `style` property of `null` will throw an error, `parseInt` doesn't get a chance.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to get the x and y position of an element, you can use `offsetLeft` and `offsetTop` instead.

```
var firstDiv = document.getElementById('firstdiv');
var xcurrent = firstDiv.offsetLeft;
var ycurrent = firstDiv.offsetTop;
```

This will get the x and y position (with respect to the `offsetParent`) whether they were set through CSS positioning or not.